# RedirectToAction does not change the URL

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, redirect

1.
I have a home page (Home / Index). Here you select the language.
Here the url is this: `"localhost:xxxx".`

2.
After selecting the language, the following is a login page (Account / Index)
Here the url is this: `"localhost:xxxx/Account/Index?language=en-US".`

3.
When entering data (Username / Password) and click on the Logon button, redirects to User / Index but the url stays in Account/LogOn

My Form:

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("LogOn", "Account")) { %>
<div data-role="fieldcontain" class="ui-hide-label">
  <label for="username">Username:</label>
  <%: Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Username, new { placeholder = "Username" })%>                      
</div>
<div data-role="fieldcontain" class="ui-hide-label">
  <label for="password">Password:</label>
  <%: Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new { placeholder = "Password" })%>                 
</div>
<fieldset class="ui-grid-a">
  <div class="ui-block-a"><button type="reset" data-theme="d">Reset</button></div>
  <div class="ui-block-b"><button type="submit" data-theme="b">Log On</button></div>
</fieldset>             
<% } %>
```

Account Controller:

```
[HandleError]
public class AccountController : Controller
{        
  public ActionResult Index(string language = "es-Es")
  {
    return View();
  }

  [HttpPost]
  public ActionResult LogOn(UserModel user)
  {
    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(user.Username, false);
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "User");
  }

  public ActionResult LogOff()
  {
    return View();
  }
}
```

Global.asax:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
  routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
  routes.MapRoute(
                  "Default", // Route name
                  "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
                 new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
                 );
}
```

How to make the url is: localhost:xxxx/User/Index ?

Comment: Just add data-ajax="false" to the form and it will work without any ugly fixes :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your `Account/Index.cshtml` view replace:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    ...
}
```

with:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("LogOn", "Account"))
{
    ...
}
```

so that you invoke the `LogOn` action on the Account controller when you submit the form and not the Index action (which simply returns the same view).

Comment: Hello!. Thanks for your answer. So as you say I have it and it still gives me the same

Comment: @user1146273, is the `LogOn` POST action hit? How does your route setup look like? Have you somehow modified the default routes generated by the new ASP.NET MVC application wizard?

Comment: The post method works well, get parameters perfectly. I have not used any Wizard

Comment: @user1146273, so how does your route setup look like in Global.asax?

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with the code you have posted so far. It should work. I have tested it on my machine and it worked perfectly fine.Do you have some custom javascript that might be interfering? Have you installed some third party NuGet packages?

Comment: The problem is when the form is created with JqueryMobile. I have no
idea why, but finally identified the problem. Thank you all!

Answer (score 6):

In your LogOn use permanent redirect:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult LogOn(UserModel user)
{
   FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(user.Username, false);
   return RedirectToActionPermanent("Index", "User");
}
```

Comment: The problem is when the form is created with JqueryMobile. I have no
idea why, but finally identified the problem. Thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

I know this question has been answered already, but it'd be easier if you use RedirectToRoute, instead RedirectToAction, it turns out that RedirectToRoute forces the url change.

Answer (score 0):

If you use jQuery mobile make sure you have the `data-url` attribute set to the correct url on the target page:

```
<div id="my-page" data-role="page" data-url="/myurl">
```

This solves the problem.